Good Polynomial lower estimates for beta function
I'm looking for polynomial lower estimates for beta function, and what I've found so far is this, which can be found in proposition 2.3 in this paper
Proposition 2.3 1.  If $0<<1$ and $ \geq $, then $\dfrac{2^{2(1-q)}}{p-q+1} \leq (,)$.
where
$$(,)=\int_{0}^1^{−1}(1−)^{−1} .$$
From this proposition it follows for example that
$\dfrac{1}{p-q+1} \leq (,).$ (1)
I wanted to know if this inequality is optimal, if it is the best possible polynomial estimate. In fact, the paper presents some other estimates, but of an exponential type. I find this condition $0<<1$ restrictive, are there estimates of type (1) without this restriction? I would appreciate it if you could refer me to works with such estimates.
Thanks in advance.

What do mean by "the best possible polynomial estimate"?

$B(x,x)\sim 2\big(\sqrt{\pi/x}\big)(1/4)^x$ is exponentially small as $x\to +\infty$ so you won't find any without bounding the parameters.

@losif Pinelis Maybe I expressed myself badly when I said, specifically I want to know when it is possible to get estimates like $\dfrac{1}{p-q+1} \leq (,)$ without the restrictions of the proposition I mentioned.

@ClaudeChaunier This estimate that you showed demonstrates a very fast decay when $x \rightarrow \infty$, I am looking for estimates of this type $\dfrac{1}{p-q+1} \leq (,).$, which are slower.

Get a moment to think over it -- no rational polynomial can be a lower bound of something decaying faster. Except 0 or useless negative values.

@ClaudeChaunier You're right, thanks for the tip.
